# How to redirect url in 5 seconds using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, url, redirect

I am using an AJAX in this form that response tru bootstrap components. How can I redirect to a certain URL but I still have to see the response from AJAX If the sign-up is successful? I have this code:

sign-up.php

```
if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
$response['status'] = 'success';
$response['message'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> &nbsp; Registered sucessfully, you may login now';
} else {
$response['status'] = 'error';
$response['message'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> &nbsp; Invalid entry, please try again.';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your AJAX response handler code, add this to the end:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.myurl.com/path";
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I have this on my handler...
    setTimeout(function(){
    if ( data.status==='success' ) {
    $('#errorDiv').slideDown('fast', function(){
    $('#errorDiv').html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data.message+'</div>');
    $("#register-form").trigger('reset');
    $('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=pcode]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#btn-signup').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign Me Up').prop('disabled', false);
     }).delay(3000).slideUp('fast');

Which part should I include that code?